# Does the naming matters in ssh keys

Tags: linux, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I am trying to clone repo from `bitbucket` using `ssh keys`.

I generated the keys with `ssh-keygen -t rsa` the name i used was `abc` and `abc.pub`.

I was not able to connect then i tried debug
`ssh -v git@bitbucket.org`

```
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ cd ~/.ssh
```

So from that i see that ssh only searches from key with name `id_rsa`

is that correct.

I remeber i had some other key name on my home computer and system was able to detect that.

I renamed abc to id_rsa and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ssh -v git@bitbucket.org -i /path/to/abc
```

Man Page says

```
-i identity_file  Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public 
key authentication is read. The default is ~/.ssh/identity for protocol version 1,             
 and ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa and ~/.ssh/id_rsa for protocol version 2. 
Identity files may also be specified on a per-host basis in the configuration 
file. It is possible to have multiple -i options (and multiple identities 
specified in configuration files).  ssh will also try to load certificate 
information from the filename obtained by appending -cert.pub to identity 
filenames.
```

Comment: [Ditto for FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html), fyi.